# Stackdriver Logging API returns response code 200, but response is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to fetch stackdriver logs via Stackdriver Logging API v2. I do this by making a POST request from google apps script project, in particular using UrlFetchApp. The thing is, it runs successfully, but the response shown in log is empty. However, when I made the same request using apirequest.io, curl and Google API explorer, I got the necessary response.

I searched extensively, but to no avail. Tried experimenting with header, url, but nothing.

```
function exportLogs () {
    var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "headers": {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    "resourceNames": [
        "projects/MyProject"
    ],
    "pageSize": 1,
    }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?key=MyApiKey', options)
    Logger.log(response)
}
```

What I want to get is some logs, but I'm only getting `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Unacceptable keys are used in `options` object.

#### Solution:

- `payload` is the only acceptable parameter for including request body.

#### Code:

```
function exportLogs() {
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, //Include  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform in scopes
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      resourceNames: ['projects/[PROJECT_ID]'],
      pageSize: 1,
    }),
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?key=MyApiKey',
    options
  );
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

#### To Read:

- [Urlfetch#params](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))
- [Logging api#entriesList](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list)
- [Setting scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)

Comment: It works, but I had to use `projectIds` (which is deprecated) instead of `resourceNames`, because for some reason it wouldn't work. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If I remove `?key=MyApiKey` from the url then I don't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason, adding an `orderBy` sort property in the request body object is the only way I could get results to be retrieved.

Also, a filter should be added to get only Apps Script logs.

```
load.filter = 'resource.type="app_script_function"';//Only from Apps Script
```

See example code at GitHub:
[Apps Script Download Stackdriver Logs](https://github.com/Blueprinter/AppsScript-Download-StackDriver-Logs/blob/master/GS_Download_Logs)

Code:

```
function exportStackdriverLogs() {
  var id,load,options,param,response;
  
  id = 'Enter your Cloud Project ID here';//See your console at:
    //https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings
  
  param = "projects/" + id;
  
  load = {};
  load.resourceNames = [param];
  load.orderBy = "timestamp desc";
  load.filter = 'resource.type="app_script_function"';//Only get logs that
     //came from Apps Script 
  load.pageSize = 1;//You will probably want more than 1 but this is for an example
  
  options = {};
  
  options.method = "post";
  options.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  
  options.payload = JSON.stringify(load);
  
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;
  options.contentType = "application/json";
  
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list',options);

  //Logger.log('response: '  + response.getResponseCode())
  //Logger.log('content: ' + response.getContentText())
}
```

Comment: Weird, but that's how I got it working as well (using the java api), by adding orderBy timestampDesc