# How to get Log with Stackdriver Logging API

Tags: google-apps-script, stackdriver, google-apis-explorer

I'm developing a chatbot using Dialogflow and I need to get full conversation log from it.

I checked [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377439/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-conversation-history-in-dialogflow) and I guessed it is able to achieve it by using Stackdriver Logging api.

I referred below page and I tried, however using this api, it occurs 403 error.
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/list

Did I use this in a wrong way?

How can I resolve this problem?

This is the error message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

This is my code where calling the api.
I used Google Apps Script.

```
function getLogs() {
  //XXXXXXXX is my project_id
  var output = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/XXXXXXXX/logs');
  Logger.log(output)
}
```

Comment: In the current stage, in order to achieve your goal, it is required to create Google Apps Script project and Cloud Platform Project, then, it is required to link them. By this, the Stackdriver API can be enabled and use it. As the result value, the method of Method: logs.list you try to use is `Lists the logs in projects, organizations, folders, or billing accounts. Only logs that have entries are listed.`. Is this result value what you want? Can I ask you about whether when you tested "Try this API" at the link you show, you could retrieve the result you want?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I guess my Google Apps script and Google Cloud platform have been linked because the linked could platform project is displayed.
I checked below way.
Apps script menu > resources > could platform project

I'll pase the result of "Try this API" in next comment.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 
cache-control: private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 174
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 15 Feb 2020 06:15:20 GMT
server: ESF
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
  "logNames": [
    "projects/XXXXX/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
    "projects/XXXXX/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event",
    "projects/XXXXX/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "projects/XXXXX/logs/dialogflow_agent",
    "projects/XXXXX/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"
  ]
}`

Comment: but when uncheck "Google OAuth2.0" the same 403 error displayed.

Comment: You must send authorization header with bearer token (can be retrieved from ScriptApp class)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the retrieved `logNames` in your replying, it is found that "Try this API" works. About `when uncheck "Google OAuth2.0" the same 403 error displayed`, I cannot understand. Especially, I cannot understand about `same 403`. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: If your GAS project has already been linked to Cloud Platform Project and the required scope is set, you can retrieve the value from the method of logs.list you want to use using the script of `var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/XXXXXXXX/logs', {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});`. This has already been mentioned by @TheMaster 's comment.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.

`but when uncheck "Google OAuth2.0" the same 403 error displayed`. 
this means "Try this API" has Credentials, when check "Google OAuth2.0" returns 200, but when uncheck it, returns 403 error.
`{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}`
So I wonder my OAuth setting is incorrect.

Comment: @TheMaster san, @Tanaike san
Thank you for your reply. I added the header and executed. And then this error displayed.

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stackdriver Logging API returns response code 200, but response is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575894/stackdriver-logging-api-returns-response-code-200-but-response-is-empty)

Comment: @TheMaster san, Tanaike san


I've resolved it.
I added API key to httprequest and add oauth Scopes to "appsscript.json".

I'll paste fixed code to answer column.
I appreciate for your cooperation!!

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this way.

1. Add my api key to http request.

```
var options = {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var logs = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/XXXXXXXX/logs?key=my_api_key", options)
```

2. Add scope to appscript.json.

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
```

Then I found `logs.list` methond is not appropriate for my goal so I need to change to `v2.entries` method.

```
function getLogs(){
var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      resourceNames: ['projects/XXXXXXX'],
      filter: "timestamp >= searchdate",
      orderBy: "timestamp desc",
      pageSize: 1,
    }),
  }

  var logs = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?key=my_api_key", options);
  Logger.log(logs);

}
```