# Stackdriver Error Logging API - error code": 400 "message": "Missing group_id." - Get error logs

Tags: google-apps-script, error-logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm using the Stackdriver Error Logging REST API with Apps Script.

The documentation is at:

https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/list

The group ID is required in the query parameter string.
I need the group ID but I don't know where to get either the group name or the group ID.  I've looked in the IAM settings:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings?authuser=0

The IAM settings have a group section, but I don't have any groups.
I have no idea where to get the group ID from.
Where can the group ID be found?

The error I'm getting is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Missing group_id.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The code I'm using is:

```
function getStackdriverLogs(){
  var entries,groupId,httpResponse,logs,options,param,projectId,url;
    
  /*
    Get StackDriver Logs -
  */
  
  /*
    The Stackdriver Error Reporting API (Error Reporting API) must be enabled - 
  
    https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/list    
  */
  
  groupId = "Put group ID here";
  projectId = "Put the Cloud Project ID here";
  
  param = 'projects/' + projectId;
  url = "https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + param + "/events";
  
  url = url + "?groupId=" + groupId;

  options = {};
  
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;
  options.headers = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
  
  options.contentType = "application/json";
  options.method = 'get';
  
  httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log('httpResponse.getResponseCode(): ' + httpResponse.getResponseCode());
  
  if (httpResponse.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    return httpResponse.getContentText();
  }

  logs = httpResponse.getContentText();
  Logger.log('logs: ' + logs)
  
  logs = JSON.parse(logs);
  
  entries = logs.entries;
  Logger.log('pgTkn',pgTkn)
  
  
}
```

Comment: Errors are grouped and each group has a id. The id of a group can be found in the url.

Comment: I looked at two different API's for getting Apps Script logs, the Cloud Error Reporting API and the Cloud Logging API.  They are different.  The Cloud Logging API has a way to filter the logs for Apps Script functions.  The only logs that I have in the Cloud Log are from my Apps Script projects, but it's possible to have logs from multiple different sources.   You could have entries in your Cloud Logging from multiple different programming languages.  To use the filter `app_script_function` see: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64530003/2946873](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64530003/2946873)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages are grouped based on a [set of criteria](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/grouping-errors). Each group can be seen in [Stack driver error reporting](https://console.cloud.google.com/errors). If a group is clicked in the dashboard, that group of error message is opened and the url looks like:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/errors/[GROUP_ID]?project=[PROJECT_ID]&time=[TIME_DATA]
```

Group ID can be inferred from the url. Alternatively(and preferably), use the [projects.groupStats.list](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.groupStats/list) end point to get all the group IDs in a given project.

Related: [Stackdriver Logging API returns response code 200, but response is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575894/)